# Word processor for math and code?

Tags: math, latex, word-processor

I'm looking for a graphic word processor who can support LaTeX such as Stack Exchange just by writing `$\formula$`, but also code writing.

It's for taking my notes in my IT - math class.

Comment: For what OS? And what is your price limit in case of paid software?

Comment: If you don't mind buying a student license I have found mathematica to be the best.  There are..cough cough...other ways to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found the perfect thing :
[Typora](https://www.typora.io/)

You can write your document live with markdown and pandoc support ( so latex is supported!).
The best software I ever found to write my domcuments!

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice Math](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/math/) with the [TexMaths](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/texmaths-1) extension.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150503/how-to-insert-latex-formulas-in-libreoffice) is some explanation from another stack question.